# Use functions with Express in Node JS: Beginner

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
function sampler(){
    const a=1;
    const b =2;
    const s=a+b;
    return s;
}

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/',(sampler),(req,res)=>{
  res.send(s);
})

app.listen(2300);
```

*What I'm trying to do?*

--> Add the variables 'a' and 'b' and send the response to the user.

I know this is pretty beginner stuff, but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for through Googling. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

The `app.get()` method takes a callback function as its second argument, but you are passing the `sampler` function instead. `sampler` should be invoked inside the callback function.

And `s` variable is not accessible because it's scope is only inside `sampler` function. You must call the function and store returned value to a variable to access it.

```
function sampler() {
  const a = 1;
  const b = 2;
  const s = a + b;
  return s;
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s = sampler();
  res.send(s.toString());
});

app.listen(2300);
```

Comment: In addition I would also look into [controllers](https://lo-victoria.com/build-a-rest-api-with-nodejs-routes-and-controllers) if you want to separate the routes and the logic.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to fix your function to be a correct middleware, since it looks like you want to use it as a middleware. For example:

```
const sampler = function (req, res, next) {
    const a = 1;
    const b = 2;
    const s = a + b;
    req.sum= s.toString();
    next();
}

app.get('/',sampler,(req,res)=>{
    res.send(req.sum);
})
```

Take a look at [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) to learn more about how to write a middleware in Express.